# Como puedo modificar esta consulta SQL

Tags: sql

SQl/HR
Mostrar el nombre, apellido y el salario de los empleados que trabajan en el
departamento de Compras y ganan el salario máximo.

```sql
SELECT 
FIRST_NAME AS NOMBRE,
LAST_NAME AS APELLIDO, 
SALARY AS SALARIO 
FROM 
EMPLOYEES 
WHERE 
DEPARTMENT_ID =30 AND SALARY= (SELECT MAX(SALARY) 
FROM 
EMPLOYEES WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID=30);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el resultado correcto cambiando con el nombre del departamento me cambia la respuesta con alguien que no trabaja en el departamento.

Elabores esta consulta pero me dice que tengo que usar el nombre del departamento no con el id
`'Shipping'=30`, AL USAR EL NOMBRE NO ME DEVUELVE EL MISMO RESULTADO.

```sql
SELECT 
FIRST_NAME AS NOMBRE,
LAST_NAME AS APELLIDO, 
SALARY AS SALARIO 
FROM 
EMPLOYEES,DEPARTMENTS 
WHERE 
DEPARTMENT_NAME ='Shipping' AND SALARY= (SELECT 
    MAX(SALARY) FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE DEPARTMENT_NAME='Shipping');
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y como podemos saber cual es correcta? En la segunda te falta la condicion de join...

Comment: Pon la estructura de ambas tablas

Comment: Falta usar alias para definir la relación entre EMPLOYEES y DEPARTMENTS !

Answer (score 0):

He intentado replicar tu escenario con variables tipo tabla. he agregado el uso de alias. Por favor prueba y nos confirmas el resultado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
DECLARE @EMPLOYEES AS TABLE (EMPLOYEES_ID int identity,FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(50), LAST_NAME VARCHAR(50),SALARY FLOAT, DEPARTMENT_ID INT)

DECLARE @DEPARTMENTS AS TABLE (DEPARTMENT_ID int identity,DEPARTMENT_NAME VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @DEPARTMENTS (DEPARTMENT_NAME) VALUES ('Shipping'),('Other')

INSERT INTO @EMPLOYEES (FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,SALARY,DEPARTMENT_ID) VALUES ('Den','Raphaely',11000,1),('Steven','King',24000,1),('Erick','Castillo',4000,2)

SELECT E.FIRST_NAME AS NOMBRE,E.LAST_NAME AS APELLIDO, E.SALARY AS SALARIO,D.DEPARTMENT_NAME FROM @EMPLOYEES as E, @DEPARTMENTS as D
WHERE E.DEPARTMENT_ID = D.DEPARTMENT_ID AND D.DEPARTMENT_NAME ='Shipping' 
AND SALARY= (SELECT MAX(E2.SALARY) FROM @EMPLOYEES as E2 
WHERE D.DEPARTMENT_NAME='Shipping' AND E.DEPARTMENT_ID = E2.DEPARTMENT_ID);
```